# mysql_list_fields including TABLE_PREFIX

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm doing a project with PHP. I need to put `TABLE_PREFIX` in the line below:

```
// work perfect without TABLE_PREFIX
$fields = mysql_list_fields(DB_DATABASE, 'TABLE_NAME'); 

// not working
$fields = mysql_list_fields(DB_DATABASE, TABLE_PREFIX, 'TABLE_NAME');
```

What do I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [no `prefix` argument](http://php.net/mysql_list_fields) for the function. you need to concatenate your prefix:

```
$fields = mysql_list_fields(DB_DATABASE, TABLE_PREFIX . 'TABLE_NAME'); 
                                                      ^----concatenation operator
```

Comment: i dont know why, i've tried before with DB_DATABASE, ". TABLE_PREFIX ." 'TABLE_NAME' but not working, and yet this one do the trick..thanks!